# dynamically select from a table name from another select in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working with PostgreSQL9.4.

I have a table "groups", defining a list of groups entities, with a column "group_table". Each group has a table with the name defined by group_table, with its data.

I want to select data from the group_table by the group_id. Can I do it as a combined query and not a plsql function?

Comment: This sounds like a bad design.  In SQL, tables should be related to each other via _joins_, which take place between the _columns_ on two tables.  It sounds as if you are storing actual table names, and then trying to look them up this way.  This won't scale, is cumbersome, and you should rethink your design.

Comment: *Can I do it with one select?* No. You can only inject the name a of a table by dynamically building the SQL string, then executing that string. So you need one query to get the table name and produce the sql string, then the produced string is (at least) the second query. You are heading down a very poor design pathway.

Comment: In our case each group has completly different columns so it would redundant to combine them to one table with a lot of null values. Also we have many hundreds to couple thousands of different groups. Each group could have hundreds of thousands to millions entries in their data table. We chose this design actually for scale reasons. Also we never select data from two different group tables in one query.

Comment: Used_By_Already, sorry I edited the question. I meant I want some compound query of two select queries of course. Just without having to save it to a variable in a plsql script.

Comment: [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)